# apply function from R to julia

Tags: r, julia

I am a total newbie in Julia world and I am a trying to call the julia mapslices function from R. However I have this following issue:

```
library(XRJulia)
japply=JuliaFunction(juliaEval("function(a) return(mapslices(sum,a,[1])) end"))
 a=array(runif(16),c(4,4))
juliaGet(japply(juliaSend(a)))
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]
#[1,] 1.083545 2.426658 2.310691 1.44339
#But
a=array(runif(32),c(4,4,2))
juliaGet(japply(juliaSend(a)))
#  Error in checkSlotAssignment(object, name, value) : 
# ‘.Data’ is not a slot in class “array”
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: I don't know XRJulia, but `function(a) return(mapslices(sum,a,[1])) end` is not valid julia code. In julia you'd say `japply(a) = mapslices(sum, a, 1)`

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard it seems to be valid Julia code! It is anonymous function similar to `a -> mapslices(sum, a, 1)` . You could probably try `map(function(a) return(a*2) end, [1,2,3])`

Comment: Thank for your help. @MichaelK.Borregaard : actually I copied the exact syntax of an example. @ Liso : the map makes R crash... The pb could be related to XRJulia ...

Comment: @user3507085 sorry I didn't meant that you need to test. I was looking at [XRJulia doc](https://rdrr.io/cran/XRJulia/api/) but it seems to be not very good described. My humble opinion is that problem is in R-library. Maybe JuliaGet could get only Vector and multidimensional array is problem? You could check it if you replace `return(mapslices(sum,a,[1]))` with `return(rand(2))` or `return(rand(2,2))` or `return(rand(2,2,2))` ?

Comment: @Liso . Yes the pb is definitely related to juliaGet. juliaGet(juliaEval("rand(2,2)")) works fine but juliaGet(juliaEval("rand(2,2,2)")) wont

Comment: Question is if you really need multidimensional arrays as result from mapslicing. What is expected result? Vector, 2 or 3 dimensional array? Could reshape in JuliaEval help? (For example if `a=rand(2,2,2)` then `reshape(a, (:))` return same 8 number which are in `a` but in one-dimensional array)

Comment: This is right. This should work, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try my package `JuliaCall`, which embeds Julia in R. The usage is quite similar to `XRJulia` in this case. The multi-dimensional array in Julia just converts to multi-dimensional array in R automatically.

```
library(JuliaCall)
julia_setup()
japply=julia_eval("function(a) return(mapslices(sum,a,[1])) end")
a=array(runif(16),c(4,4))
japply(a)
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]
#[1,] 1.083545 2.426658 2.310691 1.44339
a=array(runif(32),c(4,4,2))
japply(a)
#, , 1
#
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]
#[1,] 3.119738 3.116167 2.299303 1.96874
#
#, , 2
#
#         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
#[1,] 1.578722 1.280093 0.6427822 2.786489
```

The main difference between `XRJulia` and `JuliaCall` is that `XRJulia` connects to Julia in R while `JuliaCall` embeds Julia in R. `JuliaCall` has performance advantage over `XRJulia` when you need to transfer large vectors or matrices between R and Julia, but it will do more work in the startup of Julia (especially for the first time).

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying to install your package few weeks ago but I could not make it works. This is why I turned myself to the XRJulia.

Comment: @user3507085 Thank you for the feedback. What system are you using? Would you mind opening an issue at https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall/issues ?

Comment: Linux. Actually I dont remember exactly what the problem was, I will check this

Comment: @user3507085 The case for linux is a little complicated. Do you use RStudio? I have received some feedbacks that JuliaCall running from RStudio on Ubuntu causes RStudio to crash.